# Which should go first, test/train splitting or standardization/normalization?

Tags: machine-learning, model, normalization, standardization, data-preprocessing

I am used to normalizing everything before splitting them up until recently.

I ran into a Kaggle notebook where the author split the dataset first without anything modified. That makes me think about my previous preprocessing method. As far as I can come up, splitting the dataset first helps the model become robust because this makes it resilient to the unseen data points. But can outliers influence the model's performance if we normalize the dataset in the second place?

This is rather a discussion than a question. Any pros and cons towards both methods are welcome!

Comment: This isn't a discussion. Using test data in the normalisation is completely inappropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pre-processing is a sort of mini-model.  Anything that relies on information in the train set needs to be applied to new data.  Thus, if your model pipeline normalizes data, then the mean and standard deviation you apply for normalization should be the mean and standard deviation you learn from your train set.  Using information from the test set is inappropriate because ostensibly, you do not have access to that data at test time.

Comment: Since you don't support using any info generated based on the test set, what should we calculate the normalized values of test set? I mean, can we just apply the normalizer trained on the training set to the test set? Or, we should create another one?

Comment: No, you apply the normalizer train on the training set to the test set.  You never learn anything from the test set; it is supposed to be for testing.

Comment: Make sense! That is really eye-opening! I have made so many mistakes for a long time!